403 Forbidden with using Azure Logs ingestion API to send logs to custom table
Update on 25 June - 2 (SOLVED)
How could I have been so foolish...
I set up a secret generic and modified the deployment.yaml to assign variables. And it worked...
To sum up my questions, all were caused by not setting up the environment variables properly.

Update on 25 June - 2
After the 403 Forbidden problem with the Web APP has been fixed, however, I am now encountering the same problem in AKS. I want the containers in AKS to send logs to the same custom table as the Web APP, but they are showing the same error in the error message.


Update on 25 June - 1
I have successfully sent logs to a custom table in Log Analytics.
This was after I realized I had missed setting up the environment variables, as shown in the screenshot below.
After setting up the environment variables, it works to send logs to custom table. :)


I have published a containerized Web App on Azure running Linux OS, coded in C# .NET.
And I want to send my app logs to custom table in Azure Log Analytics.
Therefore, I follow the tutorials on Tutorial: Send data to Azure Monitor using Logs ingestion API (Resource Manager templates) and Sample code to send data to Azure Monitor using Logs ingestion API to set-up Azure environment (DCR, DCE, creating a new table, App registration) and write .NET code to try send data to my custom table.
Despite numerous attempts, I consistently received a 403 (Forbidden) error code. Even though I have waited over 30 minutes (according to troubleshooting), the issue persists.
Error messages from Azure Log stream as belowed:

Upload failed with Exception The authentication token provided does not have access to ingest data for the data collection rule with immutable Id 'dcr-'.


Status: 403 (Forbidden)


ErrorCode: OperationFailed


Content:
{"error":{"code":"OperationFailed","message":"The authentication token provided does not have access to ingest data for the data collection rule with immutable Id 'dcr-'."}}

If anyone has experienced similar issues or has any suggestions, I would be very appreciated!

I have followed the MSDoc to configure the prerequisites required to send the data to Azure monitor logs using log ingestion API.
Provide access to the registered application and your user account from the DCR as mentioned in MSDOC.
Navigate to your Data Collection Rule(DCR) instance=>Access Control(IAM)=>Add Role Assignment=> Select Monitoring Metrics Publisher role=> Select User, Group or Service principal=> Select your Application and the user account.



After assigning the role, wait for 30 to 45 min and execute the code.

I am able to run the code and got the expected response.
Code Snippet:
// Initialize variables
var endpoint = new Uri("<DCE_Endpoint>");
var ruleId = "<dcr-Immutable ID>";
var streamName = "Custom-MyTableRawData";// Stream Name

// Create credential and client
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
LogsIngestionClient client = new(endpoint, credential);

DateTimeOffset currentTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

BinaryData data = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(
  new[] {
    new
    {
      Time = currentTime,
      Computer = "Computer1",
      AdditionalContext = new
      {
        InstanceName = "user1",
        TimeZone = "Pacific Time",
        Level = 4,
        CounterName = "AppMetric1",
        CounterValue = 15.3
      }
    },
    new
    {
      Time = currentTime,
      Computer = "Computer2",
      AdditionalContext = new
      {
        InstanceName = "user2",
        TimeZone = "Central Time",
        Level = 3,
        CounterName = "AppMetric1",
        CounterValue = 23.5
      }
    },
  });

// Uploading logs
try
{
    var response = await client.UploadAsync(ruleId, streamName, RequestContent.Create(data)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (response.IsError)
    {
        throw new Exception(response.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Log upload completed using content upload");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Upload failed with Exception: " + ex.Message);
}

// Logs can also be uploaded in a List
var entries = new List<object>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    entries.Add(
        new
        {
            Time = currentTime,
            Computer = "Computer" + i.ToString(),
            AdditionalContext = new
            {
                InstanceName = "user" + i.ToString(),
                TimeZone = "Central Time",
                Level = 3,
                CounterName = "AppMetric1" + i.ToString(),
                CounterValue = i
            }
        }
    );
}

// Make the request
try
{
    var response = await client.UploadAsync(ruleId, streamName, entries).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (response.IsError)
    {
        throw new Exception(response.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Log upload completed using list of entries");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Upload failed with Exception: " + ex.Message);
}

Console Response:

Logs Uploaded to the Custom Table in Log Analytics Workspace:


Thank you for your reply. I am wondering how long it takes for your Log Analytics to receive the message? I think I might have succeeded in sending data to Log Analytics, but it's weird because it takes 7 hours to appear in my custom table...

It generally works after waiting for 30/40 min, it took 15 minutes in my case.

I have figured out what happened...my initial question has been resolved. But now I have another question about AKS. I want the container in AKS to also send logs to the custom table as Web APP; however, it encounters the same 403 Forbidden error again. Do you have any suggestions for this situation?

Assign Contributor role to the AKS cluster in Web App.

Thanks for replying me again. I figured out what the problem is. It cause by not setting up the environment variables properly again.

Thanks to Pravallika for taking the time to replicate my case.
I figured out the solution after carefully reviewing the documentation again.
Not only Web APP but also AKS, all questions are about not setting up the environment variables.
。For the Web APP
The key point is not to overlook setting the Environment variables

。For AKS
Step 1. Create Kubernetes Secret
kubectl create secret generic azure-secrets \
--from-literal=azure-client-id='<your-azure-client-id>' \
--from-literal=azure-client-secret='<your-azure-client-secret>' \
--from-literal=azure-tenant-id='<your-azure-tenant-id>' \
--namespace your-namespace

Step 2. Use Secret in the setting of Pod
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-application
  namespace: your-namespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-application
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-application
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: myimage
        env:
          - name: AZURE_CLIENT_ID
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: azure-secrets
                key: azure-client-id
          - name: AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: azure-secrets
                key: azure-client-secret
          - name: AZURE_TENANT_ID
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: azure-secrets
                key: azure-tenant-id

Step 3. Apply the deployment.
Everything is now perfectly set up.
